# Different results with local vs SymPy live - problems with division?

Tags: python, python-2.7, math, sympy

I have an equation I'm trying to solve. I get a proper result with SymPy live console, which is available on their website. Yet when I'm trying to reproduce the same result on my local computer, I'm getting a `ConditionSet` and I can't solve the equation.

The exact same equation cannot be solved locally. I'm not sure if there's maybe something wrong with the divison (but I'm importing `__future__.division`), the lack of LaTex libraries, or some other settings?

Here are the commands from SymPy live:

```
Python console for SymPy 1.0 (Python 2.7.12)

These commands were executed:
>>> from __future__ import division
>>> from sympy import *
>>> x, y, z, t = symbols('x y z t')
>>> k, m, n = symbols('k m n', integer=True)
>>> f, g, h = symbols('f g h', cls=Function)

Warning: this shell runs with SymPy 1.0 and so examples pulled from other documentation may provide unexpected results.
Documentation can be found at http://docs.sympy.org/1.0.

>>> a = Eq(309.07*(1+x)**(-1/12) + 309.07*(1+x)**(-2/12)+309.07*(1+x)**(-3/12) + 309.07*(1+x)**(-4/12) + 309.07*(1+x)**(-5/12) + 309.07*(1+x)**(-6/12) + 309.07*(1+x)**(-7/12), 1500)
>>> solveset(a, x, domain=S.Reals)
```

Result printed in LaTex:

```
          {2.17102109654962}
```

And here the local python script:

```
from __future__ import division                                                                                                                                                             
from sympy import *                                                                                                                                                                         

init_printing()                                                                                                                                                                             

x, y, z, t = symbols('x y z t')                                                                                                                                                             
k, m, n = symbols('k m n', integer=True)                                                                                                                                                    
f, g, h = symbols('f g h', cls=Function)                                                                                                                                                    

a = Eq(309.07*(1+x)**(-1/12) + 309.07*(1+x)**(-2/12)+309.07*(1+x)**(-3/12) + 309.07*(1+x)**(-4/12) + 309.07*(1+x)**(-5/12) + 309.07*(1+x)**(-6/12) + 309.07*(1+x)**(-7/12), 1500)           
b = solveset(a, x, S.Reals)                                                                                                                                                                 

print b
```

Result printed in ASCII text:

```
ConditionSet(x, Eq(309.07*(x + 1)**(-0.583333333333333) + 309.07*(x + 1)**(-0.5) + 309.07*(x + 1)**(-0.416666666666667) + 309.07*(x + 1)**(-0.333333333333333) + 309.07*(x + 1)**(-0.25) + 309.07*(x + 1)**(-0.166666666666667) + 309.07*(x + 1)**(-0.0833333333333333) - 1500, 0), (-oo, oo))
```

I'm using `Python 2.7` and `SymPy 1.0`
I would appreciate any help on this...

Comment: Maybe Sympy Live uses the development version of Sympy? In any case, using `solve` instead of `solveset` gives the answer needed. However, as you looking for a numerical solution, using `nsolve` is the best option as it will give the (same) result much faster.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what causes the different behavior, but if you tell sympy to treat your exponents as sympy integers, then you will get the same result as with SymPy Live:

```
from __future__ import division                                                                                                                                                             
from sympy import *                                                                                                                                                                         

init_printing()                                                                                                                                                                             

x, y, z, t = symbols('x y z t')                                                                                                                                                             
k, m, n = symbols('k m n', integer=True)                                                                                                                                                    
f, g, h = symbols('f g h', cls=Function)                                                                                                                                                    

a = Eq(309.07*(1+x)**(-1/Integer(12)) + 309.07*(1+x)**   (-2/Integer(12))+309.07*(1+x)**(-3/Integer(12)) + 309.07*(1+x)**(-4/Integer(12)) + 309.07*(1+x)**(-5/Integer(12)) + 309.07*(1+x)**(-6/Integer(12)) + 309.07*(1+x)**(-7/Integer(12)), 1500)           
b = solveset(a, x, S.Reals)                                                                                                                                                                 

print b
```

As to why python integers are not treated like sympy Integers in the local install I don't know. To me it seems as if SymPy Live overrides the `/` operator. To clarify this behavior try

```
print(type(1/12))
```

in your local install and in SymPy Live. The local result will be `<class 'float'>`, the SymPy Live result will be `<class 'sympy.core.numbers.Rational'>`.